# Spring Boot Mobile dependency not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm trying to use the spring-boot-mobile dependency for detecting if the user uses mobile platform ( and if so, to display on message ), but I get this error:

```
Dependency 'org.springframework.mobile:spring-mobile-device:1.1.5.RELEASE' not found 
Tag name: groupId Description : The project group that produced the dependency, e.g. org.apache.maven. Version : 3.0.0+
```

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-repo</id>
        <name>Spring Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

I'm using spring boot 2.3.0:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

I already tried mvn clean install -U, and clean install from the intelij idea.

Comment: The repos do not accept http request. Use `https://repo.spring.io/release` and others instead.

Comment: Can you try to use `<artifactId>spring-mobile-starter</artifactId>` (as per the [Spring Mobile](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mobile) instructions), and see if that fixes your problem (if so, the old project is deprecated (it's from 2015))

Comment: I tried `<artifactId>spring-mobile-starter</artifactId>` and it's still says that it's not found. I don't know what do you mean by using: `https://repo.spring.io/release`  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by downloading the .jar file and adding it in the project:

```
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> +
```

Now it works.